# How to check number of users on older versions of an app?

Tags: google-play-console

In the Google Play Console Store, I can see the active installs. I have multiple versions of my app, and I would like to check how many users are on an older version of my app.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to Statistics
2. Click the dropdown and select Users > Active Users > All users
3. Bellow that select: View by App Version

Now you can see how much users are using each version of your app.